When I walk around a pole planted obliquely, what angle does the ray from my feet to the pole make with the pole?
I plant a pole in the ground (which we assume is a flat plane).  Call the point where the pole hits the ground $O$, a fixed point on the top of the pole $Z$, and the location of my feet $X$.  I walk around the pole in in a circle $\omega$ (with center $O$) of fixed radius.
The pole isn't perpendicular to the ground: call it's minimal angle of elevation from the ground $\phi$ (so that it's maximum angle from the ground is $\pi - \phi$).  Then, as I walk around the pole, moving $X$ along $\omega$, $\angle XOZ$ changes smoothly from $\phi$ up to $\pi - \phi$ back down to $\phi$.  Call the point where the angle is minimal $X_0$, and let $f(\theta)$ be the angle $\angle XOZ$ when the arc $XX_0$ is $\theta$ radians.
Clearly, $f$ is well determined.  How do I calculate it?

My work so far: This is equivalent to the following: Let $PABC$ be an irregular tetrahedron with $BA = BC$.  Let $\theta$ be the angle $\angle ABC$.  We are given $\phi = \angle PBA$ and wish to find $f$, $\angle PBC$.
That seems like a simple setup which should be solvable via trig.  However, there is one more fact that I can't incorporate into the tetrahedron: that $\angle PBA$ is less than or equal to $\angle PBX$ for any $X$ on the circle with $B$ as its center and $BA$ as its radius.  If that fact could be incorporated into the construction of the tetrahedron, I believe this problem would be solved.
This might also be related to angle excess and the fact that the sum of the angles in a polyhedron is fixed.  I don't know how to take that further, though.

Shouldn’t it be $BA = BC$ because it seems like $B$ is the bottom of the pole? And why did you switch symbols in your work? Why not use $ZXOX_0$?

@Pranay Thanks.  1) Yes, fixed.  2) I find my intuition works better when I use a standard labeling of a tetrahedron $PABC$.  But yes, $Z = P, O = B, X_0 = A, X = C$.

Please don’t forget to accept one of the answers.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $O$ is the origin, $X_0$ is along the $x$ axis, and the ground is the $xy$ plane (which means the pole is in the $xz$ plane). Then, the direction vectors are
$$
OZ = (\cos \phi, 0, \sin \phi),\quad OX_0 =(1,0,0), \quad OX = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta, 0).
$$
All you need is the dot product of $OZ$ with $OX$:
$$
\cos f(\theta) = \cos \phi \cos \theta.
$$
As a check, we have $f(0) =\phi$ and $f(\pi) = \pi -\phi$. Another check is $f(\pi/2) = f(3\pi/2) = \pi/2$ because at this points $X$ is on the $y$ axis whereas the pole is in the $xz$ plane.

@SRobertJames You said $\phi$ is the angle of elevation, which usually means angle measure from ground. You also said the angle of elevation is $\pi-\phi$ on the other side, which is consistent with angle measure from ground.

@SRobertJames For example, when $\phi=0$, the pole is on the ground, which means it’s $z$ component must vanish. That’s consistent with what I wrote for $OZ$. The other answer switched sin and cos.

Got it, thanks.

Let's do this with some basic linear algebra.
We'll assume that the pole has length 1, and your walking circle is radius 1; we'll say that the ground is the $xy$ plane, $+z$ is up, and the pole is tilted from $+z$ towards $+x$.  This gives the pole's direction vector
$$P = (\sin \phi, 0, \cos \phi)$$
Then we can consider the walking circle.  It's in the $xy$ plane, and we'll paramaterize it as
$$X(\rho) = (\cos \rho, \sin \rho, 0)$$
We can find the angle using the dot product:
$$X\cdot P = \sum_i X_iP_i = |X| |P| \cos \theta$$
We have $|X| = |P| = 1$, and there's a bunch of zeroes that cancel stuff in the sum, so we end up with $\cos \theta = \sin\phi \cos\rho$.
Here's a desmos link to play with.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2cspz8um2q
For a perfectly vertical pole, the angle never changes: it's always exactly a right angle.  As the pole becomes more tilted, the angle function gets taller and looks vaguely sinusoidal for smallish angles before changing more and more to a triangle wave, with a perfect triangle wave when the pole lies on the ground.

Interestingly, (switching $\sin$ and $\cos$ to use angle of elevation), the curve is very well approximated by $y = \left(\phi-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cos\ x\ +\frac{\pi}{2}$

This shows a good tool: To find an angle, turn the relevant points into vectors and use the dot product formula.  That's much more direct (and easier) than trying to go triangle by triangle via trig, like the OP initially tried.

Linear algebra: Unreasonably effective
